# Automating Unity Games using Appium 1.x

Tags: unity-game-engine, automation, appium, game-development

I want to automate games developed on unity using Appium . I found this video from headspin on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FltaLelWeoU about automate unity games using Appium 2.x. But not able to get any reference how can I automate using Appium 1.x
Please share if you have any reference